# mongoose validation before save data it says done is not a function?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wanted to check email is already in database or not so i used the below code it always giving me error done is not a function don't know why this happening please help me to get out from this issue :

```
userSchema.path('email_id').validate(function(value, done) {    
  this.model('User').count({ email_id: value }, function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    } 

    // If `count` is greater than zero, 'invalidate'
    done(!count);
  });
}, 'Email already exists');
```

error is :

TypeError: done is not a function
    at C:\nodejs\school_election_system\Model\user.js:65:9
    at C:\nodejs\school_election_system\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3949:16

Comment: Can you show a "minimal" complete listing as an example please. i.e Just the schema and model definition and trying to do something that causes validate to fire. I can't reproduce this, so if you can show a listing that actually reproduces it, then it's worth looking at. All that said, simply marking as `"unique"` really does the same job, and with far less overhead.

Comment: @NeilLunn, please check this repo https://github.com/vivek9716/school_election_system all code is there please help me...

Comment: @AluanHaddad No. That's not a duplicate. The `this` keyword is meant to be used in this way for Mongoose validation triggers and other schema attached methods.

Comment: For the "author" - The idea  of "minimal" example is to provide only the code needed to reproduce "within your question" and not through external links. That said, you actually have `validate` defined "twice" for the field. You can have "either" the inline definition "or" the register ed function. But not "both". But again, you really just want "unique" here instead, or simply use `"upserts"`. Either of those approaches does not require an additional async call like you are trying to do. Works better that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found :

```
userSchema.path('email_id').validate(function (value, respond) {
return mongoose.model('User').count({ email_id: value }).exec().then(function (count) {
    return !count;
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    throw err;
  });
}, 'Email already exists.');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique validation, I recomended to use [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator)

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        email: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, required: true },
    });
    userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

Comment: yes i can try this but I want to know why the above code is not working